# pybind11 - Identify and remove memory leak in C++ wrapper

Tags: python, c++, numpy, pybind11

I have a simple C++ function that I've attempted to wrap with `pybind11` (the `ehvi3d_sliceupdate` function from the [KMAC library](https://moda.liacs.nl/index.php?page=code)). It's deep in a loop and gets called a few hundred thousand to a million times in my Python module. Unfortunately, it seems to be leaking memory (12+GB after ~700k calls) and I'm not sure what the cause might be. The wrapper that I've compiled looks like this:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "helper.h"
#include "ehvi_calculations.h"
#include "ehvi_sliceupdate.h"

namespace py = pybind11;


// Copied from main.cc
//Checks if p dominates P. Removes points dominated by p from P and return the number of points removed.
int checkdominance(deque<individual*> & P, individual* p){
  int nr = 0;
  for (int i=P.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
    if (p->f[0] >= P[i]->f[0] && p->f[1] >= P[i]->f[1] && p->f[2] >= P[i]->f[2]){
      cerr << "Individual " << (i+1) << " is dominated or the same as another point; removing." << endl;
      P.erase(P.begin()+i);
      nr++;
    }
  }
  return nr;
}


// Wrap the ehvi3d_sliceupdate function - not sure how to pass straight in
double wrap_ehvi3d_sliceupdate(py::array_t<double> y_par, py::array_t<double> ref_point, py::array_t<double> mean_vector, py::array_t<double> std_dev) {

  deque<individual*> nd_samples;

  // Get y_par and feed by individual via numpy direct access
  // https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html
  auto yp = y_par.unchecked<2>(); // y_par must have ndim = 2
  
  for (py::ssize_t i = 0; i < yp.shape(0); i++) {
    individual * tempvidual = new individual;
    tempvidual->f[0] = yp(i, 0);
    tempvidual->f[1] = yp(i, 1);
    tempvidual->f[2] = yp(i, 2);
    // cerr << i << ": " << yp(i, 0) << " " << yp(i, 1) << " " << yp(i, 2) << endl;
    checkdominance(nd_samples, tempvidual);
    nd_samples.push_back(tempvidual);
  }

  // Marshall ref_point, mean_vector, and std_dev into an array
  // (might be better ways to do this..)
  auto rp = ref_point.unchecked<1>(); // ref_point must have ndim = 1, len 3
  double r [] = {rp(0), rp(1), rp(2)};
  
  auto mv = mean_vector.unchecked<1>(); // mean_vector must have ndim = 1, len 3
  double mu [] = {mv(0), mv(1), mv(2)};

  auto sd = std_dev.unchecked<1>(); // std_dev must have ndim = 1, len 3
  double s [] = {sd(0), sd(1), sd(2)};
  
  double hvi = ehvi3d_sliceupdate(nd_samples, r, mu, s);
  return hvi;
  }

  
PYBIND11_MODULE(kmac, m) {
    // module docstring
    m.doc() = "EHVI using KMAC";

    // definie EHVI slice update function
    m.def("ehvi3d_sliceupdate", &wrap_ehvi3d_sliceupdate, "O(n^3) slice-update scheme for calculating the EHVI.");
    
}
```

There's probably a much easier way to wrap this, as I just cobbled together bits I found from the pybind11 docs and here on SO. I'm not that familiar with C++, so I might have committed some other heinous coding errors creating arrays or passing pointers using my limited knowledge. Am I creating something which needs to be cleaned up each time? At first, I thought I might need to contain my numpy arrays as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659924/returning-numpy-arrays-via-pybind11/44682603#44682603) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124695/pybind11-return-numpy-array-of-objects) previous post, but I'm only returning a double, so there's no numpy array to handle on the python side.

---

**EDIT**

I've tried changing the `tempvidual` block to use heap memory (I believe it's called?), as I read that it would clear itself up, by using:

```cpp
    individual tempvidual;
    tempvidual.f[0] = yp(i, 0);
    tempvidual.f[1] = yp(i, 1);
    tempvidual.f[2] = yp(i, 2);
    checkdominance(nd_samples, &tempvidual);
    nd_samples.push_back(&tempvidual);
```

and before returning `hvi` at the end, I tried adding `nd_samples.clear();` to clear the `deque` before returning to python, but I'm still getting an increase in memory per call to the wrapper. Is there anything else left to clean up?

---

**EDIT 2**

So it turns out part of the problem was the library itself, which leaked around > 4kb per call according to `valgrind`. Thanks (and big shout out) to the amazing help of @ajum on the [pybind11 gitter](https://gitter.im/pybind/Lobby) who practically walked me through refactoring most of the code to use `shared_ptr` and `make_shared` instead of raw pointers fixing all of the leaks in the library. This has also required a small update to the wrapper, see below. Unfortunately, even using the leak-free (I think) library and updated wrapper, I'm getting a report of:

```
==1932812== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1932812==    definitely lost: 676 bytes in 1 blocks
==1932812==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1932812==      possibly lost: 145,291 bytes in 80 blocks
==1932812==    still reachable: 1,725,888 bytes in 1,013 blocks
```

which is less than before, but I don't know what's causing it.

Edited sections of the wrapper:

```
// Copied from main.cc
//Checks if p dominates P. Removes points dominated by p from P and return the number of points removed.
int checkdominance(deque<shared_ptr<individual>> & P, shared_ptr<individual> p){
  int nr = 0;
  for (int i=P.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
    if (p->f[0] >= P[i]->f[0] && p->f[1] >= P[i]->f[1] && p->f[2] >= P[i]->f[2]){
      cerr << "Individual " << (i+1) << " is dominated or the same as another point; removing." << endl;
      P.erase(P.begin()+i);
      nr++;
    }
  }
  return nr;
}


// Wrap the ehvi3d_sliceupdate function - not sure how to pass straight in
double wrap_ehvi3d_sliceupdate(py::array_t<double> y_par, py::array_t<double> ref_point, py::array_t<double> mean_vector, py::array_t<double> std_dev) {

  // deque<individual*> nd_samples;
  deque<shared_ptr<individual>> nd_samples;
  
  // Get y_par and feed by individual via numpy direct access
  // https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html
  auto yp = y_par.unchecked<2>(); // y_par must have ndim = 2
  
  for (py::ssize_t i = 0; i < yp.shape(0); i++) {
    auto tempvidual = make_shared<individual>();
    // individual * tempvidual = new individual;
    tempvidual->f[0] = yp(i, 0);
    tempvidual->f[1] = yp(i, 1);
    tempvidual->f[2] = yp(i, 2);
    // cerr << i << ": " << yp(i, 0) << " " << yp(i, 1) << " " << yp(i, 2) << endl;
    // cerr << i << ": " << tempvidual->f[0] << " " << tempvidual->f[1] << " " << tempvidual->f[2] << endl;
    checkdominance(nd_samples, tempvidual);
    nd_samples.push_back(tempvidual);
  }

  // Marshall ref_point, mean_vector, and std_dev into an array
  // (might be better ways to do this..)
  auto rp = ref_point.unchecked<1>(); // ref_point must have ndim = 1, len 3
  double r [] = {rp(0), rp(1), rp(2)};
  
  auto mv = mean_vector.unchecked<1>(); // mean_vector must have ndim = 1, len 3
  double mu [] = {mv(0), mv(1), mv(2)};

  auto sd = std_dev.unchecked<1>(); // std_dev must have ndim = 1, len 3
  double s [] = {sd(0), sd(1), sd(2)};
  
  double hvi = ehvi3d_sliceupdate(nd_samples, r, mu, s);
  
  return hvi;
  }
```

In the output of running `valgrind` on the python test script, I couldn't identify what the issue was. An excerpt of the output with the `definitely lost` block looks like this:

```
==1932812== 676 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 212 of 485
==1932812==    at 0x4C30F0B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==1932812==    by 0x2D595F: _PyMem_RawWcsdup (obmalloc.c:592)
==1932812==    by 0x166786: _PyCoreConfig_Copy.cold (main.c:2535)
==1932812==    by 0x34C4C7: _Py_InitializeCore (pylifecycle.c:850)
==1932812==    by 0x34CCB3: pymain_init (main.c:3041)
==1932812==    by 0x3503EB: pymain_main (main.c:3063)
==1932812==    by 0x35085B: _Py_UnixMain (main.c:3103)
==1932812==    by 0x5A137B2: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
==1932812== 
==1932812== 688 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 214 of 485
==1932812==    at 0x4C33419: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:834)
==1932812==    by 0x21E8F8: _PyObject_GC_Resize (gcmodule.c:1758)
==1932812==    by 0x2345DA: UnknownInlinedFun (frameobject.c:726)
==1932812==    by 0x2345DA: UnknownInlinedFun (call.c:272)
==1932812==    by 0x2345DA: _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (call.c:408)
==1932812==    by 0x2979C7: call_function (ceval.c:4616)
==1932812==    by 0x2BE4AB: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (ceval.c:3124)
==1932812==    by 0x233E93: UnknownInlinedFun (ceval.c:547)
==1932812==    by 0x233E93: UnknownInlinedFun (call.c:283)
==1932812==    by 0x233E93: _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (call.c:408)
==1932812==    by 0x2979C7: call_function (ceval.c:4616)
==1932812==    by 0x2BE4AB: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (ceval.c:3124)
==1932812==    by 0x233E93: UnknownInlinedFun (ceval.c:547)
==1932812==    by 0x233E93: UnknownInlinedFun (call.c:283)
==1932812==    by 0x233E93: _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (call.c:408)
==1932812==    by 0x2979C7: call_function (ceval.c:4616)
==1932812==    by 0x2BE4AB: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (ceval.c:3124)
==1932812==    by 0x233E93: UnknownInlinedFun (ceval.c:547)
==1932812==    by 0x233E93: UnknownInlinedFun (call.c:283)
==1932812==    by 0x233E93: _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (call.c:408)
==1932812== 
==1932812== 1,056 bytes in 2 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 350 of 485
==1932812==    at 0x4C30F0B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==1932812==    by 0x221130: UnknownInlinedFun (obmalloc.c:520)
==1932812==    by 0x221130: UnknownInlinedFun (obmalloc.c:1584)
==1932812==    by 0x221130: UnknownInlinedFun (obmalloc.c:1576)
==1932812==    by 0x221130: UnknownInlinedFun (obmalloc.c:633)
==1932812==    by 0x221130: UnknownInlinedFun (gcmodule.c:1693)
==1932812==    by 0x221130: UnknownInlinedFun (gcmodule.c:1715)
==1932812==    by 0x221130: _PyObject_GC_NewVar (gcmodule.c:1744)
==1932812==    by 0x2344F2: UnknownInlinedFun (frameobject.c:713)
==1932812==    by 0x2344F2: UnknownInlinedFun (call.c:272)
==1932812==    by 0x2344F2: _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords (call.c:408)
==1932812==    by 0x2979C7: call_function (ceval.c:4616)
==1932812==    by 0x2BE4AB: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (ceval.c:3124)
==1932812==    by 0x206EAC: UnknownInlinedFun (ceval.c:547)
==1932812==    by 0x206EAC: UnknownInlinedFun (call.c:283)
==1932812==    by 0x206EAC: _PyFunction_FastCallDict (call.c:322)
==1932812==    by 0x20F1BA: UnknownInlinedFun (call.c:98)
==1932812==    by 0x20F1BA: object_vacall (call.c:1200)
==1932812==    by 0x28E2E6: _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs (call.c:1250)
==1932812==    by 0x1FC4A6: UnknownInlinedFun (import.c:1652)
==1932812==    by 0x1FC4A6: PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject (import.c:1764)
==1932812==    by 0x2C069F: UnknownInlinedFun (ceval.c:4770)
==1932812==    by 0x2C069F: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (ceval.c:2600)
==1932812==    by 0x205AF1: UnknownInlinedFun (ceval.c:547)
==1932812==    by 0x205AF1: _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (ceval.c:3930)
==1932812==    by 0x206D08: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (ceval.c:3959)
```

Is this due to the `pybind11` itself or the way I called it?

P.S. Not sure if it's SO style to add edits or replace the original questions with the (long) update. Thanks!

Comment: Your rewritten code which no longer uses `new` should no longer leak. Is the leak still severe?

Comment: Hi @nanofarad - it turns out the library itself was pretty leaky! I've made some fixes and I'll add more info to the question. Unfortunately, it still leaks after applying the pybind11 wrapper.

Comment: I've realised now that now the library is leak-free and I no longer use `new`, it looks like if I actually run a test by calling the wrapper from python in a `while True` loop, the memory usage is stable (or at least is not growing at a noticeable rate). Perhaps the `valgrind` output is spurious when running it with `python` but the issue seems to be fixed now. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out removing the use of `new` where possible (and adding a `delete` where it wasn't) plus replacing all the raw pointers with `make_shared` and `shared_ptr` in the base library and the wrapper actually fixed the issue. It seems using these over raw pointers will automatically release the memory once the variable falls out of scope (a knowledgeable C++ user can correct me in the comments.)

This is probably basic/obvious for C++ coders, but for non-C++ users/beginners (and for my records, if I forget), the fix was:

```
//Change declarations like these:
// vector<mus*> pdf;
vector<shared_ptr<mus>> pdf;
// mus * tempmus = new mus;
auto tempmus = make_shared<mus>();
// newind = new specialind;
auto newind = make_shared<specialind>();
// deque<specialind*> Px, Py, Pz; 
deque<shared_ptr<specialind>> Px, Py, Pz;

// Replace function signatures and headers like this
// int checkdominance(deque<individual*> & P, individual* p);
int checkdominance(deque<shared_ptr<individual>> & P, shared_ptr<individual> p);

// Parts of structs like this
struct specialind{
  // individual *point;
  std::shared_ptr<individual> point;
};

// Couldn't figure out how to change this one to remove new as it was needed in a later scope... 
// Added delete at the end after it looked like it wasn't needed
Pstruct = new thingy[n*n];
// ...
delete [] Pstruct;  // Addded this at the end.
```

In doing so, I initially got a lot of segmentation faults. I could track down the lines that caused them by using this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718998/fixing-segmentation-faults-in-c).

Although calling `valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes python test.py` resulted in the **EDIT 2** leak message, where `test.py` is just a smiple loop (plus input `numpy` ndarrays):

```py
while True:
    hvi = kmac.ehvi3d_sliceupdate(dat, ref_point, mean_vector, std_dev)
```

-- it actually looks like the memory consumption is stable and is not growing anymore. (I'm not sure why there are spurious messages from `valgrind` but they don't seem to affect the memory noticeably during the run.) Now I can run `python test.py` for a few minutes and it stays stable at around 15 MB.

Thanks to the folks at `pybind11` and Adam Thompson for taking me through the basics.

Comment: A small tip--if you don't need true sharing semantics you can consider using `unique_ptr` in some places for better performance, although you may need to use std::move in some places as they are non copiable.

Comment: @nanofarad thanks! I will have to check how to do this. Is it a replacement for `shared_ptr` or `make_shared`? (Or are they the same thing?)

Comment: It's a replacement for shared_ptr; there's a make_shared as of C++14, otherwise it would be something like `std::unique_ptr<individual>(new individual)`. A tutorial on unique_ptr should have exact syntax.

Comment: @nanofarad Thanks! If I ever come back to C++ in the future, it'll be something I'll watch out for!